# How to sort alphabetically ordered BST as frequency ordered tree?

Tags: c++, tree, unique, cpu-word

According to my homework assignment i am working on Binary Trees. The assignment is simple that reading words from in input text file and creating a BST that includes frequency data on it.

I've simply searched on it and created an implementation of alphebetically ordered BST and it is quite working for me.

But the question that i've been struggled for is that, `Rank each unique word in descending order of frequency.`

The tree is using alpabetical ordering by comparing strings and create nodes related to that... So how may i keep going with their frequencies ? Should i create a new tree as frequency balanced by using alphetically ordered tree elements ?

Any helps would be appreciated, many thanks in advance!

But how should i keep the count

TreeNode.h :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

class treeNode
{
public:
    char data[55];
    int count;
    struct treeNode *leftPtr, *rightPtr;
};



typedef struct treeNode TreeNode;
typedef TreeNode *TreeNodePtr;

void insertNode(TreeNodePtr *treePtr, char word[]);
void alphabetic(TreeNodePtr treePtr);
int sizeOfTree(TreeNodePtr treePtr);
```

TreeNode.cpp :

```
# include "treeNode.h"

void::insertNode(TreeNodePtr *treePtr, char word[55]){
    TreeNode *temp = NULL;
    if (*treePtr == NULL)
    {
        temp = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        temp->count = 1;
        temp->leftPtr = NULL;
        temp->rightPtr = NULL;
        strcpy(temp->data, word);
        *treePtr = temp;
    }
    else if (strcmp(word, (*treePtr)->data) < 0)
    {
        insertNode(&((*treePtr)->leftPtr), word);

    }
    else if (strcmp(word, (*treePtr)->data) > 0)
    {
        insertNode(&((*treePtr)->rightPtr), word);
    }
    else
    {
        (*treePtr)->count += 1;
    }
}


void::alphabetic(TreeNodePtr treePtr)
{
    if (treePtr != NULL)
    {
        alphabetic(treePtr->leftPtr);
        printf("%s\t", treePtr->data);
        printf("%d\n", treePtr->count);
        alphabetic(treePtr->rightPtr);
    }
}

int::sizeOfTree(TreeNodePtr treePtr){
    if (treePtr == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return(sizeOfTree(treePtr->leftPtr) + 1 + sizeOfTree(treePtr->rightPtr));
}
```

Main function :

```
int main()
{
    /*reading strings from the file and add them to the tree*/

    int totalSize = 0;
    char first[55];
    FILE *fp1;
    TreeNodePtr rootPtr = NULL;
    int c;
    //fp1 = fopen("%FILENAME%", "r");
    fp1 = fopen("FILENAME%", "r");
    do
    {

        c = fscanf(fp1, "%s", first);

        if (c != EOF)
        {
            //printf(first);
            insertNode(&rootPtr, first);

        }
    } while (c != EOF);

    fclose(fp1);
    //printf("%s", rootPtr->rightPtr->leftPtr->data);
    alphabetic(rootPtr);

    printf("%d\n",sizeOfTree(rootPtr));
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE :  I am direclty asked for to use BST as data structure, none of other map, hash or C++ STL structures shouldn't be used.

Comment: What is this syntax `void::alphabetic`?  Is this your actual code?

Comment: I am using this function to print the binary tree as it is requested for one mark of the assignment. I've searched it on internet and put some small things related to my structure. This is not totally same.

Answer (score 0):

You are not asked to rearrange the nodes *in-tree*. You are asked to extract the words, most common first.

The principle is quite simple. One map for each task, something like:

```
std::map<string, int> wordmap; // this is your bst.
while(in>>word){
   wordmap[word]++;
}

std::map<int, string, std::greater<int>> countmap;

for(auto word_and_count: wordmap){
   countmap[wordmap.second] = wordmap.first;
}
```

Note that this is not working code. It is intended to show the process.

Comment: Thank you Captain, but i've some limitations, i am direclty asked for to use BST as data structure, none of other map, hash or C++ STL structures shouldn't be used.

Comment: @oğuzözcan Well, the std::map is a bst. This shows you what you need to imitate in your implementation.